# Mantener color en button

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

### Busco hacer que quede asi (onClick y onMouseDown)

- se debe poder al hacer click y al manetener el click abajo
- el color lo obtengo de otro componente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function GridPrint (props){

const grid = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
              21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,
              38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,
              55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,
              72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,
              89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100];

const color = props.selectedColor;
const [num,setNum] = useState(0);

const  handleClick = (event) =>{
    setNum(event.target.name);
    event.preventDefault();        
} 

return(
    <div id="Grid">
```

### Tabla de 10*10 compuesta de buttons

Quiero mantener el color del elemento seleccionado y que no cambie al hacer click en otro button, alguna idea?

```
        <div id="GridRight">

            
            {grid.map((element) => // pinta los 100 cuadros.
                {   
                    return (
                    <button
                    className="square" 
                    name={element} 
                    key={element}
                    onClick={handleClick} 
                    style={{backgroundColor: parseInt(num)===parseInt(element) ? color : 'white'}} `Se aplica cuando el elemento en el areglo


                    >                        
                    </button>
                )}
            )}
       
                    
        </div>
        
    </div>
);
}

export default GridPrint;
```

Comment: y que has intentado????

Comment: necesitas establecer `element.style.backgroundColor = "red";` al element actual .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer lo que buscas, establece un estado donde guardes el color de cada grilla. Además, guarda también un estado que se dipare cuando el usuario presiona y levanta el click en tu grilla.

La lógica es la siguiente:

1. Si el usuario tiene el click presionado, establece la variable `mouseDown` a `true` y colorea los elementos sobre los que ocurra un `mouseOver` en esa grilla con el color que te pasan por `props`.
2. Si el usuario deja de presionar el botón de click, establece `mouseDown` a `false` y resetea la grilla a su estado inicial.

Te dejo un snippet que puedes ejecutar desde acá. Si no quieres resetear la grilla después de levantar el click, elimina la llamada a la función `resetGrid()` en la función `handleMouseUp`.

```js
const {useState} = React;

function GridPrint (props){
let grid = [];
for(let i = 1; i<=100; i++)
  grid.push({id: i, color:'white'})
  
const [gridState, setGridState] = useState(grid);
const color = props.selectedColor;
const [mouseDown, setMouseDown] = useState(false) ;

const updateGrid = (event) =>{
  setGridState(prevState => {
      return prevState.map(element => {
        if(element.id === Number(event.target.name))
           element.color = color
        return element
      })
    })    
}

const resetGrid = () =>{
  setGridState(grid);
}

const  handleHover = (event) =>{
    if(!mouseDown) return 
    updateGrid(event)
} 

const handleMouseDown = (event) => {
  setMouseDown(true);
  updateGrid(event);
}

const handleMouseUp = () => {
  setMouseDown(false);
  resetGrid();
}

return(
    <div id="Grid" onMouseDown={handleMouseDown} onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}>
            {gridState.map((element) => // pinta los 100 cuadros.         
                {   
                    return (
                    <button
                    className="square" 
                    name={element.id} 
                    key={element.id}
                    onMouseOver={handleHover} 
                    style={{background: element.color}}
                    > {element.id}                       
                    </button>
                )}
            )}    
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<GridPrint selectedColor="tomato" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
#Grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 40px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 40px);
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```